# dual monitors on ubuntu server 20.04 on pi 4

Tags: server, multiple-monitors, display, hdmi

i have a dell vga monitor with hdmi adapter. it works but not recognized by system. i try to hook up a 2nd small monitor on hdmi but not working. Ubuntu server 20.04 with gnome on pi 4 8gb not even showing dual displays in display settings.  have another on pi 4 4gb with mate---same issue not showing dual monitors in settings and not working. refresh rate is blacking out.

Comment: Did you follow the installation guide here? https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ubuntu-core-on-raspberry-pi#1-overview

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue running Ubuntu server 19.10.01(64 bit) with Ubuntu Mate (sudo apt-get install ubuntu-mate-desktop.) The Dell monitor would stay active but have a black screen.

I found the answer here:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=131&t=270539&p=1641022&hilit=dual+monitor+ubuntu#p1641022

I modified the /boot/firmware/syscfg.txt(sudo -e /boot/firmware/syscfg.txt) and added the following line:

dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d